# 134.2 kHz RFID reader for Arduino

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am looking for an Arduino-compatible RFID reader supporting [ISO 11784 & 11785](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_11784_&_11785), in order to read tags used for animals (mostly cats and dogs) identification.

I found both [RMD660](http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=16&products_id=128) and and [Sniffer Nano v2.0](http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=16&products_id=220) from [ITead Studio](http://iteadstudio.com/), but they are out of stock. Is there any alternative?

The final goal is to build an intelligent cat door, that does not require adding a new RFID tag to my cat (he already had one implanted, and doesn't wear a collar).

Comment: If your goal is _not_ to require an RFID tag why do you need an RFID reader?

Comment: He meant "does not require adding ANOTHER RFID tag to my cat". See [this Wikipedia page: Microchip implant (animal)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_implant_\(animal\))

Comment: Thanks Axeman, that's exactly what I meant. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: BTW I'm not an expert, but I don't think those tags can be easily (and reliably) read beyond the usual 10-15cm range...

Comment: That's enough, the chip is located on the left shoulder, and I plan on putting the reader at the top of the cat door. If this does not work, I may look into another alternative though.

Comment: @Wookai When my vet planted the tag on my dog, she told me that many times it is difficult for their wand to detect the tag and some times even have to turn the wand by 90* to get the tag to read. Just keep this in mind when working on your project.

Comment: @Kellenjb Thanks for the warning, I'll definitely do some tests before investing too much (time or money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reader dirt cheap from Priority1 Design.  There based in Australia but with shipping it only cost $61 ($43 for the reader + shipping).  The electronics are exposed so I needed to make a custom case for it but it works great.  They have readers for both 125 KHz and 134 KHz but both seem to read the 134 KHz chips fine.  I get my RFID tags from Oregon RFID.  Links below.

http://www.priority1design.com.au

http://www.oregonrfid.biz

Comment: @Wookai Those Priority 1 Design boards' antennas are on the PCB, resulting in a short reading distance, as it can be seen in [this](http://www.priority1design.com.au/rfidread4100.pdf) technical sheet. Check out [my tutorial](http://freshengineer.com/blog/simple-rfid-reader-module-design/) if you want to build it from scratch for very cheap.

Comment: Thanks, your tutorial looks very interesting! I'll give it a try!

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Your tutorial link seems to be broken... Do you still have it around anywhere? I'm trying to figure out how to make a large diameter antenna to go around a cat flap.

Comment: @AndyD273 Yes, I couldn't afford my hosting anymore, so I dumped it.. [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160104234121/http://freshengineer.com/blog/simple-rfid-reader-module-design) is a link to a cached page..

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Thanks for the link. I already have a 125khz reader, but I'd like to make a custom antenna coil for it with a 12inch (30cm) diameter... How did you calculate what you needed for your antenna? Unfortunately I don't have any way to see the wave form or anything like that.

Comment: @AndyD273 I guess you also don't have an LCR meter, too :(  I guess you could use online coil inductance calculators like [this one](https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/rectangle-loop-inductance).

Comment: @abdullahkahraman That cache link doesn't seem to work anymore. Here's an older cache link that does appear to load [his tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20121105225603/http://freshengineer.com:80/blog/simple-rfid-reader-module-design/).

Answer (score 3):

I have been using an Arduino UNO to decode FDX-B with some success in conjunction with the EM4095 chip tuned for 134.2kHz. I purchased a populated board from Elektor, see the article  link: http://outlet.elektor.com/contents/en-us/50-00023%20manual.pdf.

BTW you can buy a cat flap from: http://www.sureflap.co.uk/ , a bit expensive, it uses a patented technique to extend the detection range.

As for my progress, I can currently detect the cats' tags as well as a test tag and locate the header in the data stream, working on the CRC and data payload formatting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure it's a 134.2 kHz tag?  Companion animal tags in the US are commonly 125 kHz.  Some tags are non-ISO/proprietary and can only be read with the manufacturer's reader.
2. Many 125 kHz readers can be modified to read 134.2 kHz by replacing the crystal.
3. There are higher power readers that can read 12mm tags at much larger distances than what the Arduino and other simple readers can do.  They cost a couple thousand dollars though.  FYI, the world's most powerful ISO FDX reader is at Bonneville dam on the Columbia River and can read 12mm FDX-B tags at 7 feet.  It has its own HVAC system.
   http://php.ptagis.org/wiki/index.php/Site_Page_BCC_-_Bonneville_PH2_Corner_Collector

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sur it's 134.2 kHz. The specs (http://www.anis.ch/en/microchip/) say it uses ISO 11784 & 11785.

Answer (score 0):

These OEM boards will read ISO FDX-B at close range

- HID 0000-USM-01-0-01
- Priority 1 RFIDRW-E-232

Comment: Links would be nice.